# MySQL GROUP BY query question

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I have a table that contains a name of a color (teal, for example) and the associated primary color (blue). Sometimes a color entry can be the same as its associated primary color (red, red).

How can I do a GROUP BY PRIMARY_COLOR where the COLOR for each group are in alphabetical order...except when a COLOR and PRIMARY_COLOR match -- this entry needs to be at the top of the grouping.

Example:

```
COLOR    PRIMARY_COLOR
------------------------
teal     blue
magma    red
sky      blue
red      red
magenta  red
```

should result...

```
COLOR    PRIMARY_COLOR
------------------------
sky      blue
teal     blue
red      red
magenta  red
magma    red
```

Comment: are you sure you need a group by? i think you are just doing an order by

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Order by (ASSOCIATEDCOLOR = COLOR), ASSOCIATEDCOLOR`

Answer (score 1):

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN COLOR=PRIMARY_COLOR THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, PRIMARY_COLOR
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT color, primary_color
FROM colors
ORDER BY
    primary_color,
    color LIKE primary_color DESC,
    color
```